# Angular 2 @Input tag not receiving value when selector is used

Tags: angular

Currently I want to bind my data through selector but am getting nothing when I use the selector tag:

Basically I want to reuse my notifier component by passing message from other components to this component:

**notifier.component**

```
    import {Component,Output, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-notifier',
    template: `
   <div class="notice notice-success">
        <strong>{{message}}</strong> 
    </div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
      `,
    styleUrls: ['./notifier.component.css']
})

export class NotifierComponent {
    @Input() message:any;
}
```

I am sending data by using the seletor but not getting the right value:

**Sendata.component**

```
<class="main">
  <app-notifier [message]="Data i want to send is this string"></app-notifier>
</class>
```

Comment: Mymessage($event) and handled in the component.

Comment: Are you trying to send message to notifier.component or from Sendata.component to Mymessage?

Comment: Mymessage should be a function which will receive the data emitted by message

Comment: _when_ should it emit the message data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to send a string, you need to use single quotes as well, because now you are trying to send a ***variable*** named:

```
Data i want to send is this string
```

So to send that specific string, use this instead:

```
  <app-notifier [message]="'Data i want to send is this string'"></app-notifier>
```

Comment: i have accepted your answer by the way and also gave you an up vote bro,.... and thanks yes I was comitting this mistake....

Answer (score 0):

Use [Input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)

```
export class NotifierComponent {
    @Input() message: any;
}
```

**Sendata.Component**

```
<class="main">
  <app-notifier [message]="Mymessage"></app-notifier>
</class>
```

Use `[]` instead `()` to bind.
For direct string value use single quotes to indicate string literal.

```
<class="main">
  <app-notifier [message]="'Mymessage'"></app-notifier>
</class>
```

Comment: Then you should be using [Input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)..will edit my answer

Comment: then the html of app-notifier is...{{message}}, how to bind that with it

Comment: It will display when data is received. `@Input` will do it

Comment: Mymessage is a variable or string value?

Comment: Interesting that you edited your answer twice after I posted my answer ;)

Comment: I asked OP whether he is giving string value or not..previously he was asking about @Output and that was before..

Comment: Wasn't meant to "attack" in anyway, so need for explanation. Sorry, wasn't my intention to sound so whiny :P Have a great day/evening/night/morning depending on your timezone ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Why can't you use @viewchild Concept
```

**CHILD.COMPONENT.TS**

```
   @Component({
      selector: 'user-profile'
    })

    export class UserProfile {
      constructor() {}
      sendData() {
        //send data
      }
    }
```

**PARENT.COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UserProfile } from '../user-profile';

@Component({
  template: '<user-profile (click)="update()"></user-profile>',
})
export class MasterPage {
  // ViewChild takes a class type or a reference name string.
  // Here we are using the type
  @ViewChild(UserProfile) userProfile: UserProfile

  constructor() { }

    update(){
    this.userProfile.sendData();
  }
}
```